# How to run periodic process in Heroku Java app that makes web requests

Tags: java, heroku

From my understanding of the Heroku platform, they allow only one dyno per app that can handle HTTP requests. Within a Java app, my goal is to have a periodic process run once or twice a day that gets information from Facebook servers and processes it accordingly. If a background worker dyno can't handle web requests, then how should I go about writing a reoccurring process within the web dyno?

Comment: Why not write a stand-alone program that performs that task and use the Heroku scheduler add-on to run it once a day?

Comment: I was looking into an approach like this but I ran into the same issue with the web routing. The scheduler is essentially a one-off process that runs periodically and according to Heroku one-off processes can't receive HTTP traffic (refer to formation dynos vs one-off dynos at [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps))

Comment: Can you clarify why you need the process to receive web requests? If the process is supposed to "get information from Facebook servers" then it sounds like your process will be calling Facebook and not the other way around. That's perfectly possible with a one-off dyno.

Comment: Yes that's all I'm doing, it will only request information from Facebook servers. I assumed the fact that a background process couldn't handle HTTP requests meant that it couldn't handle the HTTP protocol period. I've probably assumed incorrectly, there is no issue with the operation I seek to do as a periodic process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sense, "handle HTTP requests" refers to the listen side of the connection not the send side.  On Heroku, an application can have a single web process* that listens for HTTP connections and many other processes that initiate / send HTTP requests (or connect to other non-HTTP systems).

**Note: You can allocate as many Dynos as you want, to run each process.*

To run a process that periodically makes requests to an external service (like Facebook) you can use the [Heroku Scheduler Add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler).  Then you could either store the results in one of the many [relational or NoSQL data-storage add-ons](http://addons.heroku.com) or possibly send the results to other processes via a messaging add-on like [CloudAMQP](https://addons.heroku.com/cloudamqp).

Comment: Ok got it this sounds good. My only question is does the Heroku Scheduler add-on have a time limit for how long it could run? If it allows a reasonable amount of time it should be fine but if it is less than 10-15 minutes it may not be enough time when the app really scales.

Comment: There isn't a time limit but you will get billed for however long the process runs for.

Answer (score 0):

If the platform is limiting you, why use it? 
There are other platforms that will let you perform this.
You can easily deploy java applications to the cloud using [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/) and then you use java API with no limitations what soever as far as I know. 
OpenShift is also using git, same way Heroku does. 
They are both PaaS, so the concept is quite the same, and I think it will be easy for you to try out OpenShift. 
And you can also check Google App Engine to see if it has such limitations. 
Sorry for not helping you with the specific question, I simply know that at least "one competitor" does not have such a limitation.

Comment: It may be worth looking into another PaaS in this case if there is no work around to this limitation. Would it be feasible to have another server outside of Heroku to take care of this maintenance task? (the background process only updates values within a database)

Comment: @Ryan Sasson - and where will you host this server and who will handle its deployment? won't you need it on the cloud as well?